# Rails updating boolean values in DB without submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, checkbox, boolean

Currently i am updating the **known** column which is a boolean for **notes** table by the following code

```
<%= f.check_box :known, {}, "true", "false" %>
```

But i want to update it without submitting the form like checking the checkbox should instantly change the value to true in db.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: No! You can't do like that.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX for this.

Comment: Take a look at the best_in_place gem  https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place  http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

Comment: You can do that via AJAX as others commented, but I can't help wondering if that is a good idea. I've seen that done in one situation where it was a horrible idea, and in another situation where it was an appropriate solution.